# Irish (Gaeilge) dictionary Emacs on Windows

Tags: microsoft-windows

How do I install an Irish (Gaeilge) dictionary for Emacs on Windows?

Comment: I tried ftp://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/aspell/dict/ga/aspell5-ga-4.5-0.tar.bz2, but it doesn't work

Comment: Please update your post to give the steps for what you tried and what doesn't work so that people can help you figure it out.

Comment: What package are you using? If using `ispell`, what's the value of `ispell-local-dictionary`?

Comment: I put the necessary files in Aspell. M-x ispell-change-dictionary does not give irish as an option.

Comment: Welcome to Emacs.SE! As Dan mentioned, please edit important information into your post, rather than leaving it buried in the comments. Note that [comments are considered to be "temporary 'Post-It' notes"](//emacs.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment).